# Liquid template falls when filtering a collection with 'map'

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid

After updating Jekyll to 1.2.1 i get this error when running my blog:

`Generating...   Liquid Exception: can't convert String into Integer in _posts/ru/issues/2009-06-21-xpath-prime-numbers.md`

The trace reffers to an place in the liquid which says nothing to me:

`` /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/liquid-2.5.2/lib/liquid/standardfilters.rb:108:in `[]': can't convert String into Integer (TypeError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/liquid-2.5.2/lib/liquid/standardfilters.rb:108:in `map'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/liquid-2.5.2/lib/liquid/standardfilters.rb:102:in `map'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/liquid-2.5.2/lib/liquid/strainer.rb:43:in `send'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/liquid-2.5.2/lib/liquid/strainer.rb:43:in `invoke'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/liquid-2.5.2/lib/liquid/context.rb:82:in `invoke'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/liquid-2.5.2/lib/liquid/variable.rb:102:in `render'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53:in `inject'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/liquid-2.5.2/lib/liquid/variable.rb:90:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/liquid-2.5.2/lib/liquid/variable.rb:90:in `inject'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/liquid-2.5.2/lib/liquid/variable.rb:90:in `render'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/liquid-2.5.2/lib/liquid/block.rb:137:in `render_all'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/liquid-2.5.2/lib/liquid/block.rb:124:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/liquid-2.5.2/lib/liquid/block.rb:124:in `render_all'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/liquid-2.5.2/lib/liquid/tags/if.rb:34:in `render'
... ``

After googling I got some explanation of similar problems from different ruby developers. But none of them about Jekyll.
Here I cannot change the Jekyll code but only to fix something in my blog. I do not understand what exactly.

**UPD:** I just discovered that an error appears when I use { array | map: smth} in my templates. smth is a string.

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using? Type this into your terminal: `$ ruby -v`

Comment: ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin12.0]

Comment: I just discovered that an error appears when I use { array | map: smth} in my templates. smth is a string.

Comment: What version of Jekyll are you using? `gem list jekyll` should be enough. Please, try to install RVM or rbenv and get the most recent versions of both Ruby and Jekyll!